# proof that in every directed graph if there is a cycle with a negative value, there is allways a simple cycle with a negative value.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

So i am looking for a proof that in every directed graph if there is a cycle with a negative value, there is allways a  simple cycle  with a negative value.

example (from picture above) :

Cycle : 1 2 4 3 2 5 1 with Value:-5

Simple Cycle: 1 2 5 1 with Value: -13

So tried with removing one Node and see what is happening then ,but i never seem to have recieved a solution this way. Any tips ? (maybe every cycle have simple cycles ? )

Comment: Can you prove that if there is a cycle then there is a simple cycle (without weights)?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If there is a cycle in a graph, it must consist of the union of one or more simple cycles (why?). Can we have that every such simple cycle has positive weight?